# Can tiktok videos embed automatically run when adding ?autoplay=1 or something behind the iframe id?

Tags: embed, autoplay, tiktok

Recently, I just used data-autoplay = true for facebook and autoplay = 1 for youtube. So I need some way to make the Tiktok video embed automatically play  when hovering or scrolling etc,....

Comment: I'm also interested. Any answer?